# how to import stl , mesh to Django views.py or models.py

Tags: python, django, numpy, import

I'm trying to import [stl](https://github.com/apparentlymart/python-stl), a python package for analysis of 3D models, into my Django web application. In `view.py`, I have written the following:

```
from stl import mesh
```

but when I run it I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'mesh'
```

Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please format your question and code properly (question text starts with no indent, code starts with a minimum indent of 4).

Answer (score 3):

You may have installed [stl](https://github.com/apparentlymart/python-stl/tree/master/stl) instead of [numpy-stl](https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl). Run:

```
pip install numpy-stl
```

Comment: @이상호 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it] by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.